# PHP/Windows Task Scheduler - How to create a new task from php?

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks, wampserver

I have the following code snippet which I have tried to modify to create a scheduled task in windows from php.   I tried exec, then pclose(popen($cmd)) with no success.  The php script executes but no command is invoked and I see no added scheduled task in my Task Scheduler gui.

**Question**

How can I invoke schtasks.exe from php to create a new task?

**Code Snippet**

```
    $daysList = join(", ", $days);


    $cmd = "c:\\windows\\system32\\schtasks.exe /CREATE /SC WEEKLY /D \"$daysList\" /TN \"Action Item Reminder\" /TR \"php.exe  C:\\wamp\\www\\aim\\module\\Application\\src\\Application\\Controller\\sendmail.php\" /ST 00:01 /f";

    pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  


    //echo "c:\\windows\\system32\\schtasks.exe /CREATE /SC WEEKLY /D \"$daysList\" /TN \"Action Item Reminder\" /TR \"C:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.5.12\\php.exe  C:\\wamp\\www\\aim\\module\\Application\\src\\Application\\Controller\\sendmail.php\" /ST 00:01 /f";

    //echo '/CREATE /SC WEEKLY /D "'.  $daysList .'" /TN "Action Item Reminder" /TR "C:\wamp\www\aim\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\sendmail.php" /ST 00:01 /f"'; die();

    if (isset ($activate))
    {
        $emailOptionTable->update('true', 'Activate Reminders');
        $cmd = "c:\\windows\\system32\\schtasks.exe /Change /TN \"Action Item Reminder\" /Enable";

        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
    }
    else
    {
        $emailOptionTable->update('false', 'Activate Reminders');   
        $cmd = "c:\\windows\\system32\\schtasks.exe /Change /TN \"Action Item Reminder\" /Disable";

        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));
    }
```

EDIT

**Localization of Issue**

**Apache Error Log Shows This Message**

> ERROR: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.
>
> (46,4):UserId:ERROR: No mapping between account names and security IDs
>   was done.
>
> (46,4):UserId:

What do I need to do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You need to have a user. So you should add **/RU "username"**.
    I suggest running tasks as *system*.
2. You do not need to full address.
   "c:\windows\system32\schtasks.exe" >> schtasks.exe
3. You can get feedback from command line in windows with use ">your file.txt" at end of line.
   exp: dir > "c:\Directories.txt"

**Your New Cod:**

```
    $daysList = join(", ", $days);

    $cmd = "schtasks.exe /CREATE /SC WEEKLY /D \"$daysList\" /TN \"Action Item Reminder\" /TR \"php.exe  C:\\wamp\\www\\aim\\module\\Application\\src\\Application\\Controller\\sendmail.php\" /ST 00:01 /f /RU System";

    pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r")); // OR exec($cmd);

    //echo "schtasks.exe /CREATE /SC WEEKLY /D \"$daysList\" /TN \"Action Item Reminder\" /TR \"C:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.5.12\\php.exe  C:\\wamp\\www\\aim\\module\\Application\\src\\Application\\Controller\\sendmail.php\" /ST 00:01 /f /RU System";
    //echo '/CREATE /SC WEEKLY /D "'.  $daysList .'" /TN "Action Item Reminder" /TR "C:\wamp\www\aim\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\sendmail.php" /ST 00:01 /f /RU System"'; die();

    $cmd ="schtasks.exe /Change /TN \"Action Item Reminder\" /RU System";
    if (isset ($activate))
    {
        $emailOptionTable->update('true', 'Activate Reminders');
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd." /Enable", "r")); // OR exec($cmd);
    }
    else
    {
        $emailOptionTable->update('false', 'Activate Reminders'); 
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd." /Disable", "r")); // OR exec($cmd);
    }
```

*Good luck.*

Comment: thanks a lot always we had problem in windows with task scheduler in laravel

Answer (score 1):

$daysList = join(", ", $days);

```
$cmd = "schtasks.exe /CREATE /SC WEEKLY /D \"$daysList\" /TN \"Action Item Reminder\" /TR \"php.exe  C:\\wamp\\www\\aim\\module\\Application\\src\\Application\\Controller\\sendmail.php\" /ST 00:01 /f /RU System";

pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r")); // OR exec($cmd);

//echo "schtasks.exe /CREATE /SC WEEKLY /D \"$daysList\" /TN \"Action Item Reminder\" /TR \"C:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.5.12\\php.exe  C:\\wamp\\www\\aim\\module\\Application\\src\\Application\\Controller\\sendmail.php\" /ST 00:01 /f /RU System";
//echo '/CREATE /SC WEEKLY /D "'.  $daysList .'" /TN "Action Item Reminder" /TR "C:\wamp\www\aim\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\sendmail.php" /ST 00:01 /f /RU System"'; die();

$cmd ="schtasks.exe /Change /TN \"Action Item Reminder\" /RU System";
if (isset ($activate))
{
    $emailOptionTable->update('true', 'Activate Reminders');
    pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd." /Enable", "r")); // OR exec($cmd);
}
else
{
    $emailOptionTable->update('false', 'Activate Reminders'); 
    pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd." /Disable", "r")); // OR exec($cmd);
}
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I want to add an important point
if you use ***IIS*** for your PHP server you need to add an administrator user to your IIS folder section of authentication.
and you can use ***exec()*** instead of ***pclose(popen())*** function